# Div messes up layout

Tags: html, css

So I am building a website and I have this specific div that when I try to style messes up the rest of the layout, more specifically the horizontal lines I have. The div is the one with the id and class viewer.

HTML (without javascript):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_calculator.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lines">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
        <div class="line4"></div>
        <div class="line5"></div>
        <div class="line6"></div>
        <div class="line7"></div>
        <div class="line8"></div>
        <div class="line9"></div>
        <div class="line10"></div>
        <div class="line11"></div>
        <div class="line12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="calculator" class="calculator">
      <div class="clear"><button id="clear" class="clear">AC</button></div>
      <div class="div"><button data-ops="divided by" class="ops">&#247</button></div>

      <div id="viewer" class="viewer">0</div>

      <div class="seven"><button class="num" data-num="7">7</button></div>
      <div class="eight"><button class="num" data-num="8">8</button></div>
      <div class="nine"><button class="num" data-num="9">9</button></div>
      <div class="multiply"><button data-ops="times" class="ops">&#215</button></div>

      <div class="four"><button class="num" data-num="4">4</button></div>
      <div class="five"><button class="num" data-num="5">5</button></div>
      <div class="six"><button class="num" data-num="6">6</button></div>
      <div class="minus"><button data-ops="minus" class="ops">-</button></div>

      <div class="one"><button class="num" data-num="1">1</button></div>
      <div class="two"><button class="num" data-num="2">2</button></div>
      <div class="three"><button class="num" data-num="3">3</button></div>
      <div class="plus"><button data-ops="plus" class="ops">+</button></div>

      <div class="zero"><button class="num" data-num="0">0</button></div>
      <div class="equal"><button id="equals" class="equals" data-result="">=</button></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle with my html and css:

https://jsfiddle.net/hyk1zxmt/

Thank you !

Btw, if I had paragraph elements will this happen too? And how can I prevent if from happening?

Comment: Please also include all associated code here. see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Precisely how are you trying to style #viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the divs in your layout are absolutely positioned. That rarely ends well. If you change the shape/size of the `#viewer` element, which is at the very top of the page and invisible (for example, if you get rid of it, or if you make it taller), it causes the other absolutely positioned items on the page to shift as well. (Changes to the colors and other non-box attributes of the div don't seem to cause the problem you describe.)

Since you have a black background color on each number square div in your calculator, the white line div is being hidden behind the black number square div. They're still there, you just can't see them.

You can verify this by changing the black background colors throughout your code (except the one on `body`) to be transparent, and then removing the `#viewer` div from your HTML (or setting it to `display:none`). Then you'll still see your lines, but they'll shift up because the `#viewer` div is no longer taking up any vertical space.

Ideally, I'd reengineer this code to use `grid`, rather than trying to absolutely position squares, and creating borders out of divs.